# Changing Bootstrap default container width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width, containers

I want to change bootstrap container default width, which is `1170px`.
Is it OK to override settings like this?

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: desired_width;
    }
}
```

Is that all I have to actually do?

Comment: We'll have to see more code to make sure that would actually fix the problem, but yes, it's definitely okay to override CSS rules in Bootstrap.

Comment: Please *don't* override the compiled bootstrap.min.css... it's a very bad practice! See my answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to directly edit a compiled (and perhaps minified) CSS file. It's considered a bad practice and should be avoided.

If you want to change the default width you have to recompile your Bootstrap. This depends on how you are currently using Bootstrap; if you are using a CSS preprocessor such as SASS or LESS you can just edit the variables (see [variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less)). Otherwise you can go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ in order to get a custom build.

If you are not using any preprocessor, you can fiddle with the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) and the [media queries breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints).

Answering your question you probably just want to change `@container-large-desktop` and `@screen-lg` using a [custom build](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) (assuming you are not using a preprocessor).

Comment: Ok, if I use customization, what will actually change?

Comment: By customizing your Bootstrap you can actually change whatever you want, depending on your needs. E.g. for a project I had to change the default grid to 960px, but in order to do that I also had to reduce the grid gutter.

Comment: @simone please define "override" in your answer because CSS rules can be overridden in a separate CSS file and that approach is perfectly acceptable. I get that you want to prevent modifying the original Bootstrap CSS file but you may want to make that a bit clearer.

Comment: @koala_dev I edited my answer, you're right, I wasn't clear. Hope it's clear enough now